# How to set the rotation rate of a pymunk SimpleMotor to reach a specific angle?

Tags: python, pymunk

I am trying to create a function (for deep learning) in which I can control my angle values for a robot by sending a specific list with the difference of angle, and then the motor should rotate till it reaches that angle . Setting the SimpleMotor.rate works inside the while loop when I am using keyboard controls, but it doesn't work when I am trying to use it in a function outside the while loop. Can anyone please suggest? Here is the code:

```
    def change_angle(angles):
        chassis_angle = self.chassis_b.angle*180/np.pi
        cur_angles = [self.leftLeg_1b_body.angle*180/np.pi- chassis_angle,self.leftLeg_1a_body.angle*180/np.pi-chassis_angle,self.rightLeg_1a_body.angle*180/np.pi-chassis_angle,self.rightLeg_1b_body.angle*180/np.pi-chassis_angle]
        target_angles = [cur_angles[0]+angles[0],cur_angles[1]+angles[1],cur_angles[2]+angles[2],cur_angles[3]+angles[3]]
        #time = angle/omega
        if target_angles[0]-cur_angles[0]>0:
                self.motor_ba1Left.rate = -2
                print("1")
        else:
                self.motor_ba1Left.rate = 2
                print("2")
        if target_angles[1]-cur_angles[1]>0:
                self.motor_ac1Left.rate = -2
                print("3")
        else:
                self.motor_ac1Left.rate = 2
                print("4")
        if target_angles[2]-cur_angles[2]>0:
                self.motor_ac1Right.rate = 2
                print("5")
        else:
                self.motor_ac1Right.rate = -2
                print("6")
        if target_angles[3]-cur_angles[3]>0:
                self.motor_ba1Right.rate = 2
                print("7")
        else:
                self.motor_ba1Right.rate = -2
                print("8")
        while (target_angles[0]!=cur_angles[0]) or (target_angles[1]!=cur_angles[1]) or (target_angles[2]!=cur_angles[2]) or (target_angles[3]!=cur_angles[3]):
            if target_angles[0]-cur_angles[0]==0:
                self.motor_ba1Left.rate = 0
            if target_angles[1]-cur_angles[1]==0:
                self.motor_ac1Left.rate = 0
            if target_angles[2]-cur_angles[2]==0:
                self.motor_ac1Right.rate = 0
            if target_angles[3]-cur_angles[3]==0:
                self.motor_ba1Right.rate = 0
            cur_angles = [self.leftLeg_1b_body.angle*180/np.pi- chassis_angle,self.leftLeg_1a_body.angle*180/np.pi-chassis_angle,self.rightLeg_1a_body.angle*180/np.pi-chassis_angle,self.rightLeg_1b_body.angle*180/np.pi-chassis_angle]

        self.motor_ba1Left.rate = 0
        self.motor_ac1Right.rate = 0
        self.motor_ac1Left.rate = 0
        self.motor_ba1Right.rate = 0

   

    


    simulate = True
    rotationRate = 1
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key in (K_q, K_ESCAPE)):
                sys.exit(0)
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_z:
                # Start/stop simulation.
                simulate = not simulate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_r:
                # Reset.
                self.reset_bodies()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_h:
                
                self.chassis_b.angular_velocity = -2
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_u:
                self.chassis_b.apply_force_at_local_point([0,-1500000])
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_j:
                self.chassis_b.apply_force_at_local_point([0,1500000])
                
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_k:
                self.chassis_b.angular_velocity = 2
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_w:
                self.motor_ba1Left.rate = -rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_s:
                self.motor_ba1Left.rate = rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_a:
                self.motor_ac1Left.rate = -rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_d:
                self.motor_ac1Left.rate = rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key ==K_UP:
                self.motor_ba1Right.rate = rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key ==K_DOWN:
                self.motor_ba1Right.rate = -rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key ==K_LEFT:
                self.motor_ac1Right.rate = -rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key ==K_RIGHT:
                self.motor_ac1Right.rate = rotationRate
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                print("keyup")
                self.motor_ba1Left.rate = 0
                self.motor_ac1Left.rate = 0
                self.motor_ba1Right.rate = 0 
                self.motor_ac1Right.rate = 0
                self.chassis_b.angular_velocity = 0
                #self.chassis_b.velocity = 0d
        self.draw()
        change_angle([30,40,-30,-40])
        
        ### Update physics
        fps = 50
        iterations = 25
        dt = 1.0/float(fps)/float(iterations)
        if simulate:
            for x in range(iterations): # 10 iterations to get a more stable simulation
                self.space.step(dt)
        #self.rotation()
        self.check_collide()
        #self.arm_collide_check()
        #self.printinfo()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(fps)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
sim = Simulator()
sim.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the while loop within change_angle works as intended.

Every frame you call change_angles from the `while running:` loop. Within that function you first decide a rate for the motor with the if statements. So far so good. After this the rate will be set to some value, but the motor has not yet rotated anything, because that happens in the step function: `self.space.step(dt)` which is the part that actually move the simulation forward, run the motor, apply gravity, resolves collisions etc.

After this part there is a while loop where I think the idea was to figure out if the angles had updated to the target angles. However, that will never happen, since the simulation only happens in the step function as I described above.

I think you can try to remove that while loop, and instead put a big if statement in the beginning of change_angle that checks if the target angles are reached and if so reset rate of motor to 0 and return. (And otherwise continue the existing if-statements).

One last tip: The angles are floating point numbers, e.g. 42.234567.... It is almost never a good idea to try to compare if to such numbers are exactly equal, since they might never become equal because of rounding errors. Instead its better to check if the difference is smaller than some delta, e.g. `target_angles[0]!=cur_angles[0]` becomes `abs(target_angles[0]-cur_angles[0]) < delta` where delta is a small number (e.g. `delta=0.01`)

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow! The founder of pymunk himself replying to my pymunk issue.. thanks again :)